# How to save /* in a string in Java and the Arduino IDE?

Tags: java, arduino

This is my code :

```
GPRS.write("Accept: */*");
```

But the Arudino IDE take `/*` as the starting of the comment and gives this error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing the */ from the end of a /* comment */
```

I tried to put `\` before `/*` but that didn't work. how to get rid of this ?

Comment: put  `\  between `/` and `*`.

Comment: This is a [known bug](http://code.google.com/p/arduino/issues/detail?can=2&q=817&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&id=817)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If that's Java code, you could write this as a workaround:

```
GPRS.write("Accept: */" + "*");
```

If your IDE doesn't recognize that the `/*` is in a string literal, I'd say that's a pretty big bug in the IDE.

Comment: Yeah you are right it [is a bug](http://code.google.com/p/arduino/issues/detail?can=2&q=817&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&id=817), and it was submitted more than 1 year ago to arduino's bugtracker. Seems to not be their highest priority :)